# Call WeatherAPI with HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I created Web API to receive daily temperature from OpenWeatherAPI.
I put the API  call in the MVC project; (plan to create new project later for better microservice architecture.)

Someone had mentioned in the code:

> in your HomeController you're attempting to simply just call the action like a method on an instance of WeatherController. You need to use HttpClient there as well. Also, don't new up HttpClient directly. It should be treated as a singleton

How would I conduct this? This is the original code, started programming month ago.

**MVC Page:**

```
namespace WeatherPage.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public WeatherController weathercontroller = new WeatherController();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public Async Task<IActionResult> About()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
            ViewData["test"] =  weathercontroller.City("Seattle");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**API Controller:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] 
public class WeatherController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("[action]/{city}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> City(string city)
    {
        Rootobject rawWeather = new Rootobject();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");
                var response = await client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid=APIkey&units=metric");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                rawWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(stringResult);
                return Ok(rawWeather);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
            {
                return BadRequest($"Error getting weather from OpenWeather: {httpRequestException.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}   

public class Rootobject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Weather[] weather { get; set; }
    public string _base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

**This works in my project:**
https://localhost:55555/api/weather/city/washington

[Retrieve Data From Third party Openweather Api](https://jonhilton.net/2017/01/24/retrieve-data-from-a-third-party-openweather-api-using-asp-net-core-web-api/)

[Should We Call Web Api from Mvc Application in Same Solution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246380/should-we-call-web-api-from-mvc-application-in-same-solution)

Answer (score 2):

It roughly means you should use dependency injection .

1. Don't create an instance of HttpClient every time when you need it , just ask for an instance of HttpClient instead .
2. Extract your code of getting weather in the weather controller into a service , and ask for the service both in weather controller api and home controller

The `WeatherService` :

```
public interface IWeatherService
{
    Task<Rootobject> CityAsync(string city);
}

public class WeatherService : IWeatherService{
    private HttpClient _httpClient ;
    public WeatherService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory){
        this._httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient();
    }


    public async Task<Rootobject> CityAsync(string city){
        Rootobject rawWeather = new Rootobject();
        this._httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");
        var response = await this._httpClient.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid=APIkey&units=metric");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(stringResult);
    }

}
```

The new WeatherController :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] 
public class WeatherController : ControllerBase
{
    private IWeatherService _weatherService;

    public WeatherController(IWeatherService wetherService ){
        this._weatherService= wetherService;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]/{city}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> City(string city)
    {
        try
        {
            var rawWeather=await this._weatherService.CityAsync(city);
            return Ok(rawWeather);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Error getting weather from OpenWeather: {httpRequestException.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

The new HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IWeatherService _weatherService;
    public HomeController(IWeatherService wetherService ){
        this._weatherService= wetherService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
        ViewData["test"] =  await this._weatherService.CityAsync("Seattle");

        return View();
    }

}
```

The ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddHttpClient();
services.AddSingleton<IWeatherService ,WeatherService>();
```